# Change HTML output link on a page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a bunch of links being output on a page and I need to target one of those and change the link.

Here is the output:

```
<div class="event-detail">
    <h3>
       <a href="http://www.old_link.com">Conference</a>
    </h3>
</div>
```

**(Note: The CSS class "event-detail" is being used multiple times on the page.)**

Replace www.old_link.com with www.new_link.com.

And then also add a **target="_blank"** at the end if possible.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
$('a[href=http://old_link]').attr('href', 'http://new_link').attr('target', '_blank');
```

This will get all links containing `http://old_link` in their `href` attribute and set the attributes as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [attribute selector](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp):

```
jQuery( '[href="http://www.old_link.com"]' ).attr({
     'href', 'http://www.new_link.com',
     'target', '_blank'
});
```

Comment: But if you have the chance to add an ID as @Adosi mentioned, that is the best solution.

Comment: Thanks Kau-Boy! I can't add an id.

Comment: Than the above should do what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$('div.event-detail a[href="http://www.old_link.com"]').attr('href', 'www.new_link.com').attr('target', '_blank')
```

you're selecting the "a"s in the page belonging to that div/class